# SQL Oracle - Insert a record into the same table if a certain criteria is not met

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two tables: **rate_card** and **rate** configured as follows:

```
create table rate_card (RateCard varchar(13), Currency varchar(3));    

insert into rate_card values('2DaysUSD','USD');
insert into rate_card values('3DaysUSD','USD'); 
insert into rate_card values('2DaysJPY','JPY');`table`


create table rate (Currency varchar(3),Rate varchar(19));

insert  into  rate values ('USD','0.6');
insert  into  rate values('JPY','0.4');
```

I want to get the output as below:

[image: Output]

Yellow once are to be shown when I run the query as `Ratecard = '1DaysUSD'` is not available.

For others I simply used `Union` to display three Records 'Spot', 'Today', 'Tomorrow' as below:

```
select c.RateCard, c.Currency, 'SPOT' from rate_card c, rate r where c.Currency = r.Currency
union
select c.RateCard, c.Currency, 'Today' from rate_card c, rate r where c.Currency = r.Currency
union
select c.RateCard, c.Currency, 'Tomorrow' from rate_card c, rate r where c.Currency = r.Currency;
```

Could you please advise me on the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using multiple subquery and `connect by` as following:

```
Select RateCard, 
Currency, 
rate, 
Case lvl when 1 then 'Spot'
         When 2 then 'Today'
         Else 'Tomorrow' 
end as type
From
  (select c.RateCard, 
          c.Currency, 
          r.rate  
     from (Select ratecard, 
                  currency 
             from rate_card
           Union
           Select &&your_inpur_rate_card, 
        substr(&&your_inpur_rate_card, length(&&your_inpur_rate_card - 2)) 
          from dual) c 
     join rate r 
     on c.Currency = r.Currency)
 Join
 (Select level as lvl 
    from dual 
  connect by level <= 3)
 on 1=1;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: in the Union Query we are hardcoding it to one RateCard... 1. Can we insert that record for all currency, second yellow part will be missing --> when i use like "select '1DayUSD',substr('1DayUSD',5, length('1DayUSD')) from dual". 2. Group by Currency and check if it does not have RateCard = '1DayUSD' then only insert .

Comment: Hardcoding is necessary as 1DaysUSD and 1DaysJPY are actually harcoded values. You need multiple unions for it.

Comment: I am not sure for a given day how many rate cards i will get, it can be 2,3 or 4...if rate card is not received then i do not want showing that three records 'Spot', 'Today', 'Tomorrow'.... is there any other way you can suggest.

Comment: That must be the other question with proper actual and expected output with multiple scenarios